# Database migration scripts and versioning with timestamps

Tags: database, svn, migration, version, flyway

We are trying to use Flyway (http://flywaydb.org/) to apply our database migration scripts.

Most people are using timestamp versions like this: 20140527112103__alter_some_table.sql
Either generating these files from a bash script or a maven/ant task.

What about the problem of a developer generating a file on Monday, working on a task for a few days and then committing the migration script. It will now be out of order and possibly conflicting with other scripts committed in the meantime.

Any way to add the timestamp to the filename during commit?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn outOfOrder mode on, then all should be fine. Unles eg developer A creates index on column that developer B removed in the mean time. But developer A should pull latest changes and test the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is simply to rename it immediately before committing and you should be ok.

Comment: Wouldn't that break my dev database?
working on migration 20140528113435_adding_a_table.sql, I've applied it to my local dev database.

rename it to 20140601113435_adding_a_table.sql before committing.
next flyway:migrate will run it again, causing a duplicate table error.